# `php-cgi` executable consoles out php version and content type of php-cgi

Tags: php, linux, windows

When I run my `php-cgi` executable from OS command prompt, it also send back content type and PHP Version as an stdout inclusion. However, in php.exe this is not visible in Windows.

Command:
`php-cgi index.php`

Code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode(array('$_SERVER' => $_SERVER));
?>
```

###### PHP-CGI Output:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

{"$_SERVER":{"ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\\ProgramData","APPDATA"......}
```

###### PHP Output:

```
{"$_SERVER":{"ALLUSERSPROFILE":"C:\\ProgramData","APPDATA"......}
```

Is there a way I can avoid the powered by and default content type being shelled out when using php-cgi? Is there a setting? I did not find any in php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`php-cgi -q index.php`

`-q   Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output.`

---

To suppress "X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.3"

`php-cgi -d expose_php=off index.php`

Comment: If I need the headers of http and not just "X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.3" what do I do? Is splitting lines the only way?

Comment: @Gary fortunately you can.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Bad docs look up on my part. @shingo